# how to make nutch crawl file system?

Tags: filesystems, nutch, web-crawler

not based on http,

like http://localhost:81 and so on,

but directly crawl a certain directory on local file system,

is there any way out?

Answer (score 4):

***From the Nutch Wiki:***

**How do I index my local file system?**

http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/FAQ#head-c721b23b43b15885f5ea7d8da62c1c40a37878e6

1) crawl-urlfilter.txt needs a change to allow file: URLs while not following http: ones, otherwise it either won't index anything, or it'll jump off your disk onto web sites.
      Change this line:

```
  -^(file|ftp|mailto|https):

  to this:

  -^(http|ftp|mailto|https):
```

2) crawl-urlfilter.txt may have rules at the bottom to reject some URLs. If it has this fragment it's probably ok:

```
  # accept anything else +.*
```

3) I changed my nutch.xml to include the following:

```
<Parameter override="false" name="plugin.includes" value="protocol-file|protocol-http|urlfilter-regex|parse-(msword|pdf|text|html|js)|index-(basic|anchor)|query-(basic|site|url)|response-(json|xml)|summary-basic|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)"/>
```

Comment: regex-urlfilter.txt needs a change

Answer (score 1):

nutch has the Intranet crawling available.  you can read the details [here](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/IntranetRecrawl)